# Scroll ng-grid to a particular column

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

My ng-grid columns have 24 time slots of a day like 12:00 AM, 1:00 AM etc. 
I want to scroll ng-grid to the current time.
E.g if the current time is 9:24 AM, then I want to scroll ng-grid to the 9:00 AM column. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a plunker that shows how to scroll to a particular column:
http://plnkr.co/edit/I578x1Q9MrPw7P0jFFNM?p=preview

You could use the undocumented scrollLeft() function of the grid to programmatically scroll to the column you wish. Adjust your code as desired for the column width (I used 90). This assumes that all columns defined are visible.

```
$scope.scrollToColumn = function(newColumnIndex) {
  var scrollTo = $scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.$viewport.scrollLeft() + (newColumnIndex * 90);
  $scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.$viewport.scrollLeft(scrollTo);
}
```